# Subclassing QUiloader and reimplementing createWidget function of it

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtgui

I needed to read widget classnames, names etc from gui loaded via QUiloader. 
And I got answer here that I needed to subclass QUiloader and reimplement its method.

I have MainWindow, and via menu/toolbar I load the file, and show it. And when I load I want to know what elements are in that gui to work further with them. 
The code I got from a user here:

```
class UiLoader : public QUiLoader
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
QStringList *wlist;
UiLoader(QObject *parent = 0) : QUiLoader(parent) {}

virtual QWidget* createWidget(const QString &className, QWidget *parent =0, const   QString &name = QString())
{
    QWidget* widget = QUiLoader::createWidget(className, parent, name);
    //here do my stuff with className, parent, name
    return widget;
}
};
```

I used Uiloader to load my file. And it is working.

My question now is how I intercept createWidget before returning widget, I want to get the list of widget and then return Widgets. 
I do not know how what is the efficient way to create a list as simple as this one:
   0=>TextBox, 1=>Button, ... 
I really do not care about the structure I just need to know which one comes first and what it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't reimplement class loader at all honestly.. May be only if you need to 'inject' something into existing code which use QUiLoader a lot.. but in general only thing you need:

```
 pWidget = ...->createWidget(...);

 QList<QWidget *> widgets = pWidget->findChildren<QWidget *>();
```

here you go, your widgets contains list of all form components..

Comment: By Reimplement you mean subclassing? And why should I do that?

Comment: yes I mean you don't need to subclass QUiLoader to get a content of widgets on newly created form.

Comment: But using the above method, I cannot get the pWidget className, objectname() method gives the name which does not necessarily the name of class of that object. So how can I get from widgets the list of (QPushbutton, QLineEdit ...)?